# Appeared at one moment from nowhere error in the discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Sitting and studying information about the discord.py 0.16.12 I was interested in the function discord.Client.edit_role(server,role,parametrs*)
I ran into a problem(An hour before that everything worked)

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ROG\Desktop\trash\dsbt\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/ROG/Desktop/trash/dsbt/rainbown_rolle/testbd.py", line 10, in on_ready
    await bot.edit_role(sr, rl, colour=discord.Colour(((rgb[0] << 16) + (rgb[1] << 8) + rgb[2])))
  File "C:\Users\ROG\Desktop\trash\dsbt\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2860, in edit_role
    yield from self.http.edit_role(server.id, role.id, **payload)
  File "C:\Users\ROG\Desktop\trash\dsbt\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 169, in request
    print(data['retry_after'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Bot code

```py
import discord
token="token"
bot=discord.Client()
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    rgb = [255, 0, 161]
    sr= discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == '403945874780061707',bot.servers)
    rl = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.name == "Обыватель", sr.roles)
    print(type(sr),type(rl))
    await bot.edit_role(sr, rl, colour=discord.Colour(((rgb[0] << 16) + (rgb[1] << 8) + rgb[2])))
bot.run(token)
```

Comment: I tried to use google to solve the problem but found nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the endpoint returned some response body that was just text, not a json.
[discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) expects responses with status 429 (rate limited) to be a json it can turn into a dictionary.  So it's trying to access the text like a dictionary, which fails.

According to [this commit](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/commit/dea3ba5eb7c99f54c72b11f3e3f7b8f41649e779) which fixes this issue for the rewrite branch, it may be that you've been banned by Cloudflare.  Try updating your bot to the new version, but you will most likely have to host your bot somewhere else to get around whatever ban they have in place.

Comment: I work on my home computer, and changing my version will kill all the work I did, but thanks anyway

Comment: Is it possible to unlock?